# How to execute function after any task triggered by gulp watch has finished

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have a litte gulp task serving files, and watching my source. I'd like to do something (OS notification) anytime a gulp task (triggered by gulp-watch) is finished.

So given:

````
gulp.task "watch", default_tasks.concat(["serve"]), () ->
    gulp.watch ["app/**/*.css"], ["css"]
    gulp.watch ["app/**/*.coffee"], ["js"]
    gulp.watch ["app/src/**/*.templates.jade"], ["templates"]```
````

I'd like something like:

```
gulp.task "watch", default_tasks.concat(["serve"]), (() ->
    gulp.watch ["app/**/*.css"], ["css"]
    gulp.watch ["app/**/*.coffee"], ["js"]
    gulp.watch ["app/src/**/*.templates.jade"], ["templates"]
).on "finish", ->console.log "done"
```

I realise I could add `.pipe().on "end", -> console.log "Finished!"` to every task. But I'd like one catch-all solution on my watch task if possible.